# node's module function return value empty/undefined?

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I'm trying to get the html encoded table row value, returned from the slqLite based logger. As I'm new to node modules I'm stuck at:

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:');
var html = '';

module.exports = {
  readHtml: function() { 
    var html = ''; // optional but does not work here as well
    db.serialize(function() {
      db.each("SELECT rowid AS id, info FROM logger", function(err, row) {
        html = html + '<tr><td>' + row.info + '<td><tr>'; << html is growing
        console.log('Log: ' + row.info); << working
      });
    });
    console.log(html); // html gets empty here!
    return html; 
  }
}
```

So have no value returned from:

```
var sysLog = require('logger');

sysLog.init();
sysLog.write('test string1');
sysLog.write('test string2');
console.log(sysLog.readHtml());
```

It has to be very simple to be solved ...
node is 6.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is directly related to a very common issue when starting with JavaScript:

[How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Which shows the simplest way to receive results of an asynchronous operation, such as `db.each` is using a callback.

```
function readHtml()
  var html = ''
  db.serialize(function() {
    db.each(..., function(err, row) {
      // this line executes sometime later
      // after we already returned from readHtml()
    });
  });
  // this line executes right after the call to db.serialize
  // but before db.each calls the callback we give to it.
  // At this point, html is '' because we still didn't read any rows 
  // (they are read asynchronously, sometime later)
  return html;
}

readHtml(); // <-- this is always '' because rows are read at a later point
```

To solve this, you would need a function that will be called with a callback like this:

```
readHtml(function(html) { // <-- this callback gets called once all rows are read
  console.log(html);
});
```

Your situation also has an additional complication that `db.each` calls its callback once for every row. By looking at the [docs](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaseeachsql-param--callback-complete), you can see that `db.each` accepts an additional `complete` callback when all rows are read. You can use this callback to signalize reading is done and pass the `html` results.

Here's how you can define `readHtml`:

```
function readHtml(callback) { // pass in a callback to call once all rows are read and all html is accumulated
  var html = '';
  db.serialize(function() {
    // read all the rows and accumulate html as before
    db.each("SELECT rowid AS id, info FROM logger", function(err, row) {
      html = html + '<tr><td>' + row.info + '<td><tr>';
    }, function() { 
      callback(html); // use the second callback to signal you are done and pass the html back
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation and sorry for my basic  node knowledge. It will be a good lesson for the future :)

Comment: No problem mate, glad to help :)